# Is there a way to write a function that takes l-val ref or r-val reference as input params?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

**Motivation:**

I have a function

```
func(const string& s);
{
    //...
}
```

of course this wont work:

```
func("hello" + " " + "world");
```

this solves that problem:

```
func(string&& s);
```

Is there a way to write func so that it automagically works with both r-value refs and l-value refs?

Comment: "this solves that problem" To be honest, if that solves the problem, that looks very much like a compiler bug.

Comment: It was an simplified example that was wrong, because I didnt understand the problem... Cat++ explanation is the correct reason... I forgot that result is char array, not std::string... noobish mistake :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rvalues bind to const lvalue refs with no problem. The problem with your code lies in types. You need at least one `std::string` for the overloaded operator+ to be used.

```
func(std::string("hello") + " " + "world");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can use the reference collapsing behavior of templates:

```
template <typename S>
func (S && s)
{
    //...
}
```

This preserves l- and r-valueness as well as constness.